# Compiling C code from a Java program

Tags: java, c, runtime.exec

I am trying the following code to compile an external C program with a Java program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr=rt.exec("cmd /c PATH=%PATH%;c:\\TC\\BIN");
        pr=rt.exec("cmd /c c:\\TC\\BIN\\TCC.exe c:\\TC\\EXAMPLE.c");
        pr=rt.exec("c:\\TC\\EXAMPLE.exe");
        BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        int exitVal=pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exited with error code "+exitVal);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

but I am getting:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\TC\EXAMPLE.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

The compilation process is not working, so what else can I do to compile my C code?

Answer (score 3):

Please use the [Processbuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API for this, The documentation has an example of how to use the various flags.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are calling the compiled program before it had the chance to be generated.
You should wait on the call:

```
pr=rt.exec("cmd /c c:\\TC\\BIN\\TCC.exe c:\\TC\\EXAMPLE.c");
```

To finish before you try calling the compiled output.

Comment: so do i need to use some wait command to make the same program able to compile and execute the code?

Comment: You can just call rt.waitFor() It will wait for the process to end and gives you the exit value of the thread.